# how to find one character from multiple same character on string by regex

Tags: java, regex

Example:
Dear sir, No. Employee is (PM/23333999) 10) i want thank you.(MA/IERPER) i want resigned.

Hi sir,

regex : \d{1,2}+(?:(\)))

result: **10)** and **99)** and **)**

What is regex pattern can i using to get result only '**10)**' from split the string?

Comment: it is not clear, further explanation please

Comment: Your pattern is equal to `\d{1,2}+\)`. Try `\d{1,2}(?=\))`

Answer (score 3):

Your pattern is equal to `\d{1,2}+\)`, i.e. your pattern consumes and returns `)`.

You may use

```
\d{1,2}(?=\))
```

where `(?=\))` is a [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that will require the presence of `)` but won't return it in the match. Also, note that `{1,2}+` here will behave the same as a non-possessive, greedy `{1,2}` quantifier (as there are no other ways to match the string before `)`), so no need adding the `+`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qF2Rcj/1).

In Java, declare it as

```
String regex = "\\d{1,2}(?=\\))";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that:

`^.*\) (.*) i want t.*$`

But, Let's improve the regex:

`^.*\([^\)]*\) (\d+\)).*$`

Answer (score 0):

since you are saying to match only `10)` try the following

```
\d{1,2}+\)(?!.*\d{1,2}+\))
```

[demo and explantion here](https://regex101.com/r/vK5YBl/3)